# SQL Syntax error in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching around and couldn't find a problem like mine. I'm getting a syntax error, but no matter how i look at it, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

It goes like this:

```
            <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['proj_id'])||!empty($_POST['task_uid']))
            die("Invalid proj_id or task_uid.");

        $query = "
        SELECT  pm.id,
                pm.proj_id,
                pm.task_uid,
                pp.pipeline_name,
                pm.proj_pipeline_order,
                pcrs.gestor_projeto,
                pcrs.prioridade,
                pcrs.tecnologia,
                pcrs.resp_programa

        FROM    projetos_main pm

        INNER JOIN projetos_pipeline pp
                  ON pm.task_uid = pp.task_uid

        RIGHT JOIN pcrs
                  ON pp.pcr = pcrs.num_doc

                 WHERE pm.proj_id = ".$_GET['proj_id']." 
                 AND pm.task_uid = ".$_GET['task_uid']."

            ";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $pipeline = $row ['pipeline_name'];
        $ordem = $row ['proj_pipeline_order'];
        $gestor = $row ['gestor_projetos'];
        $tecnologia = $row ['tecnologia'];
        $gestorPortfolio = $row['resp_programa'];
    ?>
```

is that where clause wrong? The dots are just to shorten the select. I get the message

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND pm.task_uid =' at line 20"

Comment: Can you show the actual query - expanded out with the values of proj_id & task_uid

Comment: You're checking `$_POST` for the variables at the top, then using `$_GET` in the SQL itself. The variables probably aren't defined.

Comment: You're using both $_GET and $_POST, is that intended? What exactly does proj_id and task_uid contain? Can you echo the contents of $query?

Comment: there is not space before `AND`. add space before it

Answer (score 0):

it may be issue with quotes, try this

```
SELECT  pm.id,
                pm.proj_id,
                pm.task_uid,
                .
                .
                .
                pcrs.resp_programa

        FROM    projetos_main pm

        INNER JOIN projetos_pipeline pp
                  ON pm.task_uid = pp.task_uid

        RIGHT JOIN pcrs
                  ON pp.pcr = pcrs.num_doc

                 WHERE pm.proj_id = '".$_POST['proj_id']."'
              AND pm.task_uid = '".$_POST['task_uid']."'
```

Also confirm existence of $_GET['task_uid' and $_GET['proj_uid']

Comment: That removed the syntax error, but now i can get no information to be shown on my page. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using $_GET['task_uid'] and $_POST['task_uid'] at the same time. It may the issue you are not getting data in $_GET['task_uid'] same is the case for $_GET['proj_uid']

Comment: Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: If adding quotes fixed the syntax error - then I would suspect that  $_GET['proj_uid'] returns blank or invalid data - so the where clause fails. Can you show the actual query.

Comment: please use WHERE pm.proj_id = '".$_POST['proj_id']."'
              AND pm.task_uid = '".$_POST['task_uid']."' instead of $_GET[] values

Comment: Using $_POST seemed to solve it. Thank you everyone.